# Validation flexible valid URI

Tags: php, regex, validation, url

i would to make a validation the URI is valid or not. I know this question has been ask before but i could find the flexible one, which it countain some rule

1. should put `http://` or `https://`
2. validate host is true and flexible ex : `localhost`, `example.com`, `www.example.com`, `sub.domain.com`, `198.123.456.678`
3. should contain top-level domain (such as .com or .org and any else)

if the rule break, the response should tell which rule is false

so if the url :

`https://example.com`, `http://localhost`, it would return `true`

`example.com` should be false, and the response is domain should be the domain must use either http or https

`http://www.example` should be false, because the domain does not include top-level domain

`https://198.123.456.678` and this one should be true too

those are what i expect

thank you

Comment: It would help if you'd reference the question you're mentioning and, if you've tried to extend/modify the code from this question, include it here.

Comment: To begin, start to split the url into parts using `parse_url`

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using PHP, you can use `[FILTER_VALIDATE_URL]`.

```
<?php
  $uri = "https://www.stackoverflow.com" ;

  if(filter_var($uri, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
    echo("$uri is valid") ;
  }
?>
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php for additional flags.